# Rails public files only showing with cookie on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, assets, public

Recently I've run into the issue that the public files of a rails application only load if there is a cookie present.  I originally noticed this because Google reported that it couldn't find our robots.txt file.  Later I realized that it seems to apply to all of our public files for some reason.

For instance, upon visiting this site, the content is blank.  http://80000hours.org/robots.txt
(If it's not blank, remove the cookies from the website).

However, when I load the main page at http://80000hours.org/, and then go back to /robots.txt, the page loads correctly.

I'm quite confused what could create this issue and how to go upon debugging it.  Looking back on my commits it doesn't seem like I changed anything substantial during the period where it broke.  The Memcache add-on for the website shut down around a week before this happened; I never set up a replacement, but wouldn't think this would have caused the issue.

The issue also does not exist locally, only on the production and staging Heroku instances.  The full codebase is [here](https://github.com/80000Hours/eighty-thousand-hours), the issue occurred around November 14th.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough, it was Memcache.  I added the new Heroku Memcache add-on service, Memcachier, and it worked fine without the cookie.  I'll check tomorrow if Google successfully find the /robots.txt file or not, but I'm assuming it will.